# Its going in else statement I'm not able to identify error

Tags: android, android-studio, error-handling, http-response-codes

I am not getting any error but it is going in else statement.I Don't know how to resolve it help me about it.

```
if (response instanceof HttpResponseException) {
                    HttpResponseException exception = (HttpResponseException) response;
                    switch (exception.getStatusCode()) {
                        case 401:
                            Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Please login again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Utils.startActivityWithFinish(mActivity, PhoneNumberActivity.class);
                            break;
                        case 500:
                            Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        
                 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This just means that `response` is not a `HttpResponseException`, but could be any other `Exception` or none at all (Successful?).

To find out what kind of class it is, you can print the class name in your else-block:

```
Toast.makeText(mActivity, "reponse is an instance of: " + response.getClass().getSimpleName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

The name should give you a clue already. If it is another exception, it looks like your preceding try-catch is to general and catching away all exceptions. Replace it with a less general one:

```
try {
    // Your networking code
} catch (HttpResponseException httpResponseException) {
    response = httpResponseException;
}
```

Now the app should crash when running your code and deliver you the stacktrace with the information what is going wrong.